# Amazon Game Circle Whitelist error

Tags: signature, whitelist, amazon-gamecircle

I want to ask You about Whitelist in GameCircle.
I had testing my app with testing boundle ID and my key, like they wrote in tutorial.
But now I'm wondering about if this signature and boundle id (package name) is needed when I publish my app or is forbidden to have there listing?

For example 
i i got in my GameCircle->Whitelist 
Package Name                            Signature
com.xxxxxxxxx_companyname.gamecircle    xxxXXXxxXXxx=
thats what i had used for testing GameCircle
and now I want to publish my app, as I have asked.
Signature and boundle id (package name) is needed when I publish my app or is forbidden to have there listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitelist entry is still needed.

Any app that uses GameCircle must be whitelisted using the package name and a hash of the certificate used to sign its apk.  (Amazon calls this hash the "certificate signature.")  During testing, your app is signed with your debug cert, so its signature is the one you specify.

As part of the publishing process, however, Amazon signs your app with Amazon's own certificate instead.  GameCircle recognizes this as a special case and creates a "virtual whitelist entry" for your app when Amazon-signed, using the original whitelist entry to identify the package.